# How to avoid the read command cutting the user input which is a string by space

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script to read multiple inputs from the user
Here is the command:

```
read -a choice
```

In this way, I can put all the inputs in the `choice` variable as an array so that I can extract them using an index.

The problem is that when one of the inputs, which is a string has space in it, like

```
user1 google.com "login: myLogin\npassword: myPassword"
```

the `read` command will split the quoted string into 3 words. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Why are you using `read -a` if you don't want to split the input at spaces?

Comment: Here is my command:  read -a choice and then type in  user1 google.com "login: myLogin\npassword: myPassword".  It's supposed to have 3 parameters, but the string is cut into 3 parts.

Comment: What's the difference between 3 parameters and 3 parts?

Comment: `read` doesn't process quotes to keep things as one word.

Comment: It just uses `$IFS` to split it into words.

Comment: I see. Thanks. And is there any other command that can get multiple users' inputs like read?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I might go try another way

Answer (score 1):

`bash` doesn't process quotes in user input. The only thing I can think of is to use `eval` to execute an array assignment.

```
IFS= read -r input
eval "choice=($input)"
```

Unfortunately this is dangerous -- if the input contains executable code, it will be executed by `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tab instead of space as a field delimiter. For instance :

```
 $ IFS=$'\t' read -a choice
value1  value2  a value with many words ## This is typed

 $ echo ${choice[2]}
a value with many words
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Given risk of using `eval`, and the fact the input seems to have only two types of tokens: unquoted, and quoted, consider using scripting engine that will put all text into proper format that will be easy to read.

It's not clear from the example what other quoting rules are used. Example assume 'standard' escaped that can be processed with bash @E processor.

The following uses Perl one liner to generate TAB delimited tokens (hopefully, raw tabs can not be part of the input, but other character can be used instead).

```
input='user1 google.com "login: myLogin\npassword: myPassword"'
tsv_input=$(perl -e '$_ = " $ARGV[0]" ; print $2 // $3, "\t" while ( /\s+("([^"]*)"|(\S*))/g) ;' "$input")
IFS=$'\t' read -d '' id domain values <<< $(echo -e "${tsv_input@E}")
```

Or using a function to get more readable code

```
function data_to_tsv {
    # Translate to TSV
    local tsv_input=$(perl -e '$_ = " $ARGV[0]" ; print $2 // $3, "\t" while ( /\s+("([^"]*)"|(\S*))/g) ;' "$1")
    # Process escapes
    echo -n "${tsv_input@E}"
}

input='user1 google.com "login: myLogin\npassword: myPassword"'
IFS=$'\t' read -d '' id domain values <<< $(data_to_tsv "$input")
```